# Wide to narrow characters

Tags: c++, windows, string, stl

What is the cleanest way of converting a std::wstring into a std::string?  I have used W2A et al macros in the past, but I have never liked them.

Comment: That depends on what kind of conversion you'd like to do. It's obvious that characters that exist in ASCII can be narrowed down easily, but what about characters that don't exist in the character set used by `char`? Or which have different encodings? Do you care about those? Basically, do you want *correct* conversion, or just something that works for english characters?

Comment: In this particular case, it is safe to assume all characters read are in narrow format.  I am reading in a file that contains nothing but narrow characters, however I am trying to return this information via an interface that returns wide strings.  However, a full answer for more cases would be very informative.

Comment: Also, when I write out his file I have to turn my wstrings into narrow characters.  In this case I may have to go for the generic square display character.

Comment: Amazingly not yet fully solved in 2023 for console on Windows 10 and after.

Perhaps the most succinct comment is here:


https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/issues/3491#issuecomment-1592462853

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most native way is `std::ctype<wchar_t>::narrow()`, but that does little more than std::copy as gishu suggested and you still need to manage your own buffers.

If you're not trying to perform any translation but just want a one-liner, you can do `std::string my_string( my_wstring.begin(), my_wstring.end() )`.

If you want actual encoding translation, you can use locales/codecvt or one of the libraries from another answer, but I'm guessing that's not what you're looking for.

Answer (score 5):

What you might be looking for is [icu](http://site.icu-project.org/), an open-source, cross-platform library for dealing with Unicode and legacy encodings amongst many other things.

Comment: Thank you, this will be useful in other projects.

Answer (score 4):

Since this is one of the first results for a search of "c++ narrow string," and it is from before C++11, here is the C++11 way of solving this problem:

```
#include <codecvt>
#include <locale>
#include <string>

std::string narrow( const std::wstring& str ){
    std::wstring_convert<
        std::codecvt_utf8_utf16< std::wstring::value_type >,
        std::wstring::value_type
    > utf16conv;
    return utf16conv.to_bytes( str );
}
```

- `std::wstring_convert`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert
- `std::codecvt_utf8_utf16`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8_utf16

Comment: Note that this is deprecated as of C++17, replaced by... something

Comment: Caveat Emptor 2023: don't try this at home on your Windows machine

https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/issues/3491#issuecomment-1592462853

Answer (score 2):

If the encoding in the wstring is UTF-16 and you want conversion to a UTF-8 encoded string, you can use [UTF8 CPP](http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/) library:

```
utf8::utf16to8(wstr.begin(), wstr.end(), back_inserter(str));
```

Comment: Thank you, I like the look of this.

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps. This one uses std::copy to achieve your goal.

http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-193852.html

Comment: But it does nothing more than invoke the implicit conversion from `wchar_t` to `char`, which is basically an assignment of the integer value. It only works for the characters that exist in both encodings, and have the same representation in both.

Comment: Well to convert from A to B, there must be an equivalent of A in the domain of B. There must exist a mapping.. not clear on what you mean by "same representation in both".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the "cleanest" but I've used copy() function without any problems so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

string wstring2string(const wstring & wstr)     
{
    string str(wstr.length(),’ ‘);
    copy(wstr.begin(),wstr.end(),str.begin());
    return str;
}

wstring string2wstring(const string & str) 
{
    wstring wstr(str.length(),L’ ‘);
    copy(str.begin(),str.end(),wstr.begin());
    return wstr;
}
```

http://agraja.wordpress.com/2008/09/08/cpp-string-wstring-conversion/

Comment: Standard coding practice note: you make one extra copy of each string when passing parameters by value - pass them by const reference instead.